# How do I access Anaconda environment from R reticulate if it is in my WSL home directory?

Tags: python, r, conda, reticulate

I have a working anaconda distribution (can install conda environments/packages and use them in Python). Now I'm trying to use an anaconda environment in Rstudio using the reticulate library but it can't seem to find my anaconda environments. I use the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

Here is the what happens when I look at my environments in WSL:

```
conda env list
```

> ## conda environments:                                                                                                                                                                 #                                                                                                                                                                                     base                     /home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3
>
> emcee_env
> /home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/envs/emcee_env
> py_conda_test
> /home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/envs/py_conda_test
> pymc3Env
> /home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/envs/pymc3Env
> pymc3_env
> /home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/envs/pymc3_env
> pymc_env
> /home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/envs/pymc_env

And now, when I try to see these environments in R using reticulate (and in a R markdown file):

```
library(reticulate)
myenvs=conda_list()
print(myenvs)
```

> ```
>       name                                                                       python 1            3
> ```
>
> C:\Users\Owner\.julia\conda\3/python.exe 2      mcmcEnv
> C:\Users\Owner\.julia\conda\3\envs\mcmcEnv/python.exe 3
> base
> C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\r-miniconda/python.exe 4
> r-reticulate
> C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate/python.exe
> 5       PyMOL2
> C:\Users\Owner\Schrodinger\PyMOL2/python.exe

As you can see, none of my conda environments are there. Plus, I have tried specifying which conda to use with this command:

```
use_condaenv("pymc_env")
```

> Error in use_condaenv("pymc_env") :    Unable to locate conda
> environment 'pymc_env'.

But it can't find it. And I can't specify the path either, because it is under a path from my WSL home. Here is an example:

```
use_condaenv("\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\osgrinds\mnt\c\Users\Owner\anaconda3\envs\pymc_env\bin\python")
```

> Error: '\h' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting
> ""\wsl$\Ubuntu\h"

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

The two OS seem to be independant. I guess, RStudio is installed on the Linux system. Maybe installing Rstudio on WSL too can be a solution.